# Macro Component not available in Classic Console

Tags: service, component, classic, macros

I'm trying to get the Macro utility available on my Cases page lay out in Salesforce Classic, but the component doesn't appear in the Console Components list. Does this component need to be custom made? I would assume it's a standard component/action that can just be added to the page layout.

Comment: Have you reviewed the prerequisites for Macros https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=macros_getting_started.htm&type=5?

Comment: Yes I did, I read all help articles I could find, but for some reason the macro component doesn't show up on my Classic page. I do have it on my utility bar in Lightning. Thank you though!